# Query-specified return tuple has n+ columns but crosstab returns n

Tags: sql, postgresql, crosstab

I have the crosstab query which can return value for 31 days, the problem is when I execute the query for month consisting of 30 days I encountered the below error

Query-specified return tuple has n+ columns but crosstab returns n.

Query

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(SELECT id, present FROM attendance) AS ("id" int,"1" boolean,....."31" boolean)
```

I want the 31st column need to be filled with `null`.

Or is it possible to create a sql function like below and used it to generate the required columns as per the length_of_the_month

```
len_month = 30
counts = 0
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION days_as_column (counts integer, len_month integer)
  RETURNS varchar
AS $$
while (counts < len_month):
counts = counts + 1
print '"%s" varchar(10),' % (counts) 
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

Comment: Not with `crosstab`. You'll need to modify the inputs to add a dummy 31st day.